# Local Tomcat Server with https CorsHandler returns secure JSESSIONID cookie but blocks insecure JTENANTSESSIONID_dev cookie

Tags: tomcat, cookies, sapui5

I have Local Tomcat Server setup with https CorsHandler url.
The tomcat server returns secure JSESSIONID cookie with the following web.xml config.

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
        <max-age>10800</max-age> 
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
  </session-config>
```

There is one more cookie being set by NEO JAVA SDK in file tenant_session_cookie.properties.
The properties are defined below:

```
cookie_name_prefix=JTENANTSESSIONID_??
secure=true
http_only=true
```

This cookie is returned with HttpOnly attribute but **does not have Secure** attribute which causes my app to block cookie for browser.
How can i set all cookies to secure through configuration without adding any extra code?